# Adding controls at runtime

Tags: excel, office365, vba

I'm absolutely frustrated. I want a button to be there to allow a user to duplicate two ComboBoxes in the next row. (Click, copy, insert row below, paste.)

Nothing I've done so far has worked. I've tried copying and pasting the OLE object to clipboard, but that copies the name as well. I'm stuck unable to access the object after creation. Creating a new object from scratch isn't working either. Sometimes it copies the combobox's name I have in by default (created pre-runtime). I've even started fresh with a new copy. I have noticed after creating the first copy, the following are named ComboBox2, 3, 4, and so forth.[image]

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=50, Top:=80, Width:=100, Height:=15
```

If this were VB.NET, it'd be no problem. (Create instance, set properties, add handlers, add to control collection.) Would MS Access be more suitable for my project? Probably, but the target users don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

The code you were using above is creating a new control instead of copy the control. Did you want to rename the control added by yourself?
If I understood correctly, we can get the OleObject we added and change its property as we wanted.

Here is an example wiring using VBA that add the combobox to the next row and rename it:

```
Dim combo As OLEObject

Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Set combo = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=Selection.Left, Top:=Selection.Top, Width:=48, Height _
    :=15)

combo.Name = "combox_newName"
```